# Is it called to use in Descriptive Programming?

Tags: qtp

Can anyone tell me if this method called be Descriptive Programming ?

Do not take the code too seriously It's just important for me to know if it is Descriptive Programming

Here is the code:

```
SystemUtil.Run "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Google Chrome"
Browser("Google").Navigate "http://www.facebook.com"

Browser("Google").Page("Facebook - Log In or Sign").WebEdit("pass").SetSecure "5c3ef1e5b64a84ed86a36f8aadc230ae63adc4fd83e4" 
Browser("Facebook").Page("Facebook").WebButton("Log In").Click


Browser("Facebook").Page("Facebook").Link("משרות הייטק ושיווק ללא ניסיון").Click
Browser("Facebook").Page("Facebook").WebEdit("Search").Set "משרות הייטק ושיווק ללא ניסיון"
Browser("Facebook").Page("(2) ‎משרות הייטק ושיווק").Link("משרות הייטק ושיווק ללא ניסיון").Click
Browser("Facebook").Page("(3) משרות הייטק ושיווק").WebButton("u_fetchstream_1_17").Click
Browser("Facebook").Page("(3) משרות הייטק ושיווק").WebMenu("Top PostsSee most relevant").Select "Recent PostsSee most recent posts first"
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you're using the object repository to describe objects. Descriptive programming is when you *don't* use the object repository.

E.g:

```
Browser("title:=.*").Page("title:=.*").Link("text:=משרות.*").Click
```

Or:

```
Set Desc = Description.Create()
Desc("text").Value = "משרות הייטק ושיווק ללא ניסיון"
Desc("text").RegularExpression = False
Browser("title:=.*").Page("title:=.*").Link(Desc).Click
```